# Add sound player in table or pandas

Tags: streamlit

```py
result = st.file_uploader("Upload", type=["wav", "ogg", "mp3", "mp4"], accept_multiple_files=True)
```

I need to display table with audio player in each row, something like this:

[image: Streamlit-like dataframe with sound player on every row]]

Does anyone have a solution?